# Uncompatible source code - Erroneous sym type :jlabel1.setIcon

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, netbeans-8, cannot-find-symbol

Im using the drag and drop option to create a UI for my school project. After customizing the code to enable to image to shown by replacing the label it wont run. Tried changing the project properties but rather I get a "Cannot_find_symbol"

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"cannot find symbol"* is a compiler error that has nothing to do with icons or resources.

Comment: Displays "Uncompitable source code" on the console

Comment: That's a Netbeans message. The **useful** message is 'cannot find symbol'. It should not only indicate a line number (you might need to click on the error message) and indicate which symbol cannot be found. BTW - fixing compiler errors is something we all need to do, better to learn how, now.  **Where is the MRE / SSCCE?** Without that, we can only guess what the actual problem is (& most of us don't like guessing).